# Traveling the Camino Trail during Covid

Tags: spain, portugal, walking

I am an American who plans to do the Camino Trail via the Coastal Portuguese way. I am wondering what the difference in travel restrictions means to walkers in both Portugal and Spain, and if towns I plan on traveling through will each have their own regulations.

I am completing the planning and traveling without an agency. I am also not a native Portuguese or Spanish speaker, so reference sites should be accessible in English without a translator.

Comment: Do you live outside the Schengen Area? At present there are restrictions on residents of the United States on entering the Schengen Area.

Comment: Spain recently entered a renewed state of emergency, provisionally until March 2021. I wouldn't come here until next summer if I were you, or even delay the trip to 2022.

Comment: Why on earth are you planning such a trip right now... _stay at home_!!

Comment: you're obviously aware that there is a pandemic out there and that Spain is badly hit right now. yet you are planning to go there somehow?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**This is more an extended comment than an answer. The answer right now is simple: you cannot do that and there is no a reasonable date estimation on when you will be able to do the Santiago Trail again.**

It's impossible to give you a response for the near future, but it is possible to give you an answer for right now: you can't do the trek.

This starts with the fact that [you quite likely can't fly to Spain](https://ec.europa.eu/info/live-work-travel-eu/health/coronavirus-response/travel-during-coronavirus-pandemic_es).

You haven't told us what your route is, but right now all routes are closed. [Most areas in Spain are closed](https://www.rtve.es/noticias/20201105/mapa-confinamiento-comunidades-autonomas-coronavirus/2049416.shtml) (you cannot cross some borders between towns and *comunidades* and, of course, you cannot cross from Portugal to Spain except with proof that you are doing so for work).

In addition to that, most hostels and hotels along the route are [closed or have restrictions](https://www.culturaydeporte.gob.es/consejo-jacobeo/para-el-peregrino.html). Your best bet could be a tent (also it's safer; you probably don't want to share a room with unfamiliar people who might be carrying the virus).

Anyway, the situation is changing continuously and could change at any moment. [Rumors](https://www.lasprovincias.es/sociedad/salud/gobierno-pone-fecha-20201103185217-nt.html) are that a complete lockdown may be enforced in the upcoming weeks. But maybe in 3 or 4 months everything will open up... or not.. you can't make any plan.

Comment: I'd be very wary of travelling internationally right now.  As Ivan said, the situation has changed so quickly that planning is basically out of the window.  For example, I've had to cancel 4 separate trips this year because the accommodation was forcibly closed - sometimes at only a few days notice (I'm UK-based, but I imagine it's similar for our Iberian cousins).  Honestly, I'd look at holidaying domestically for the foreseeable future.